# VS2017 command line build issue

Tags: cmd, build, visual-studio-2017, devenv

I have installed both VS2008 and VS2017 on same machine. During test I found that if I set VS2018 build environment firstly by command: %VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat, then reset to VS2017 environment by command: %VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat. The reset will report following error:

> [ERROR:team_explorer.bat] Directory not found: "C"\Program
>   Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDECommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer" [Error:VSDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encounterred errors.
>   Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***

If I just set VS2017 build environment by %VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat. No error occurs. 
Does anyone meet this issue?

Comment: I reported this issue on Microsoft developer community, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/150019/vs2017-command-line-build-issue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround...Use SetLocal and EndLocal to set local build environment.

```
SetLocal
Call %VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat
EndLocal
call %VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat
```

Save above command to a bat file and call it. The error disappeared.